# Remove certain strings from file with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Is there a way to search and remove an arbitrary string contained in a file using gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace), very easy to use